# How do I scan url for a specific string with spaces and special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using stringscanner on my request URL in order to get the name of the user's currently selected category, but I've been having difficulty dealing with spaces and special characters.

```
request.url.scan(/\?category=\w+/).to_s.gsub('?category=', '')
```

URL examples followed by result

```
http://localhost:3000/search?category=dog&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93 => ["dog"]
http://localhost:3000/search?category=dog.com&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93 => ["dog"]
http://localhost:3000/search?category=dog+cat&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93 => ["dog"]
```

I'm trying to get ["dog"] ["dog.com"] and ["dog cat"], but am currently stuck. Any ideas?

Note: Considering removing spaces from categories and replacing them with dashes as multiple spaces could be problematic, but if it's possible to create one function to rule them all, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Rails, is there a reason you're not just using `params[:category]`?

Comment: You're welcome :)  If you're new to Rails, definitely going through a tutorial, either book, or online, and/or reading through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) is my strong recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to extract params then you could use [parse_query](http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Utils/parse_query) :

```
uri = "http://localhost:3000/search?category=dog+cat&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
result = Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI(uri).query) #=> {"category"=>"dog cat", "search"=>"", "utf8"=>"\xE2\x9C\x93"}
result["category"] #=> dog cat
```